# EF 2.1 + Npgsql + ExecuteSqlCommand = syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npgsql, ef-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

Since EF Core 2.1 the SQLs are checked for injection. That's fine.

But what's the correct way to pass the arguments into `ExecuteSqlCommand`?

```cs
var content = "whatever";
```

...

```cs
var command = @"NOTIFY test, '{0}'";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, content);
```

> Executes "NOTIFY test, '@p0'". That's wrong.

```cs
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"NOTIFY test, {content}");
```

> Message: 42601: syntax error at or near "$1".

```cs
var command = $"NOTIFY test, {content}";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
```

> Works, but "warning EF1000: The SQL expression passed to 'FromSql' embeds data that will not be parameterized. (...)". 
>   Wrong. That's exactly what I'm trying to fix.

```cs
var command = @"NOTIFY test, @Content";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, new SqlParameter("@Content", content));
```

> InvalidCastException: "value must be an NpgsqlParameter." Oh, well.

```cs
var command = @"NOTIFY test, @Content";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, new NpgsqlParameter("@Content", content));
(or)
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, new NpgsqlParameter("Content", content));
```

> Message: 42601: syntax error at or near "$1". SERIOUSLY?

```cs
var command = @"NOTIFY test, {0}";
(or)
var command = @"NOTIFY test, $1";
(or)
var command = @"NOTIFY test, @Content";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, new NpgsqlParameter{Value = content});
```

> Message: 42601: syntax error at or near "$1".
>   I quit.

Am I missing something?

- .NET Core 2.1.301
- EF Core 2.1.1
- Npgsql 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL simply doesn't support parameters in `NOTIFY` statements... If you try with a regular DML such as `SELECT` or `INSERT` everything should work.

If you really want to parameterize the notification, you can still do client-side string interpolation but be sure to sanitize user input otherwise you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: According to the manual, postgres does support the payload parameter for NOTIFY statement. `NOTIFY channel [ , payload ]`. But maybe we don't understand each other. My question i only about raw string command parametrization. You're telling me, that when the string command will be an INSERT statement, the argument will be used in the query? There is some query analyzer in the process who decides which parameters will be passed to the placeholders?

Comment: PostgreSQL (and Npgsql) supports parameterization, which means that the SQL contains a placeholder and the parameter is sent separately. This prevents SQL injection and improved performance (same SQL can be prepared and executed several times with different parameters). This has nothing to do with the fact that NOTIFY accepts parameters (channel, payload). PostgreSQL doesn't allow parameter placeholders anywhere, but only in certain places in certain statement types - and the notify channel isn't one of them.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Would you mind pointing to the NpgSql documentation describing the correct format for passing parameters to other statements, e.g. `SELECT`?

Comment: @zaitsman take a look at the getting started docs: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I am missing something I guess:

While looking at the documentation(http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html)
there is a sample such as this

Also, could you show sample table structure?

```
var connString = "Host=myserver;Username=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase";

using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    // Insert some data
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data (some_field) VALUES (@p)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p", "Hello world");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // Retrieve all rows
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT some_field FROM data", conn))
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read())
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
}
You can find more info about the ADO.NET API in the MSDN docs or in many tutorials on the Internet.
```

based on "NOTIFY test, " I have no idea what are you trying to do